# Styling 2 different classes of jQuery UI selectmenus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'd like to have 2 different styles (classes) for select menus on my site. I don't want to use IDs since there can be numerous drop downs on the same page.

So for example:

```
<div class="row">
  <select class="style1">
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
      <option>Option 3</option>
  </select>

  <select class="style1">
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
      <option>Option 3</option>
  </select>

  <select class="style2">
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
      <option>Option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

However, when I create the selectmenus with the javascript call:

```
$("select").selectmenu();
```

It doesn't transfer the class name to the selectmenu it creates (it only creates an id based on the original one plus "-button").

Is there a way of using classes to style a jQuery UI selectmenu?

Thanks.

Comment: Not clear with this statement "It doesn't transfer the class name to the selectmenu it creates (it only creates an id based on the original one plus "-button")."

Comment: If the ID of the select is for example "selectmenu" then the ID of the jQuery UI select will be "selectmenu-button" as here: <span id="selectmenu-button" class="ui-selectmenu-button ui-widget... However, if we add a class to the original select, jQuery UI seems to ignore this when creating the selectmenu.

Answer (score 0):

Since the new select created by jQuery UI always immediately follows the original select in the markup, I was able to find a solution by using the adjacent sibling selector (+).

In the CSS:

```
select.style1 + .ui-selectmenu-button{}
select.style2 + .ui-selectmenu-button{}
```

If anyone has a alternative solution, feel free to share, thanks!